# Fixing overflow without min height

Tags: html, css

I tried everything to fix text overflow issue under how it works section [here](http://www.chakraco.club). But I dont want to fix it using `min-height` because I dont know what the height will be eventually. Any guidance would be extremely appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display:flex; and flex-direction:column; property to .home-hiw class.

```
  .home-hiw {
    background: #E9E8E8;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;           /*change dispay block to display flex */
    flex-direction:column;   /*add flex direction */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope this is what u r expecting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `min-height` because you don't know the actual height that's going to be used, but you can indeed use min-height with the same values as bootstrap 4 uses

(Without having to call bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

add this to home-hiw-step class